# Pass options to package loaded as tabularray library

Tags: siunitx, tabularray

Tabularray emulates commands in some other packages and therefore requests that you enable them with `\UseTblrLibrary` instead. One such package is siunitx. When loading siunitx normally, one could pass options to it; unfortunately, when one loads siunitx as a tabularray library, one cannot pass options to it, or at least I cannot figure out how to. Proof below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{retain-explicit-plus}{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num{+5}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {lS}
    }
        Hey & +1 \\
        Ho & +2 \\
        Hee & +40 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

When compiled, the document produced has no leading plus signs. How can I remedy this behavior?

(My personal problem is to do with leading pluses, but I think the form of the problem is more general, so I'd appreciate answers which are similarly general.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the order of things, if you use `\PassOptionsToPackage` after the package ran its code things are already too late to get picked up, you have to use that macro before a package is loaded to make it work.

So if you use the following you get leading signs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\PassOptionsToPackage{retain-explicit-plus}{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num{+5}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {lS}
    }
        Hey & +1 \\
        Ho & +2 \\
        Hee & +40 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I meant to delete test.tex after compiling this and instead deleted every .tex file in my directory. FML. Still, very prompt and helpful answer, thank you!

Comment: @Canyon unmount your file system, NOW!

Comment: Alas, I have no live usb and I'd be able to recreate most of my work by the time the shops open tomorrow anyway... luckily it's just a few hours of work wasted and not a whole semester

Comment: @Canyon you can also `grep` your device for contents of the file you still remember, that should save you a lot of work. I haven't read through the article, so I'm not sure how accurate it is, but take a look here for the basic idea: https://lovethepenguin.com/linux-recover-deleted-text-files-using-grep-749551c3e12b?gi=b95806689914